# Is it possible or practical to change the drfault look of WinForm control items?

Tags: winforms, powershell, user-interface

I am working on a flat style user interface and many parts can work autonomously as widgets or smaller tools. For some of those, it would add an extra level of customizability and desktop appeal if i could change the basic look and feel of the CIs.

For instance, could I change the basic WinForm form (`[Windows.Forms.Form]`) appearance to resemble the outline of a dog-eared piece of paper? I would want to do different ones, so, a permanent change to the static method isn't what I'm looking for.

How about changing a button (`[Windows.Forms.Button]`) so that it has rounded edges? What about making it a circle?

I know that with many other things like this, the solution would be to create a completely new object that acts exactly like the object you want it to be and make it take on your intended appearance and behaviours. That is much more than I would like to do (I think).

So, barring the above-mentioned, is this possible in PowerShell? If it is, could someone point me in the right direction or maybe give me a rough explanation? It would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: take a look at the components from devexpress. They can do that and you create your own themes where just about everything is possible. But they are not free

Answer (score 0):

Yep there are some modifications you can do.

For Example:

```
$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $true
$Button.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(0,0,0,0)
$Button.ForeColor = "Tomato"
$Button.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 9.25)
```

I'm not shure about the border, but I now a cool tool.
[AdminScriptEditor](http://www.itninja.com/community/admin-script-editor)

Install and run ASE.
Create a new Powershell File. Then go to "Tools" in the menubar and open the Script Form Designer.

There you can "draw" / build your Form. When you select an Item, on the right side of the Script Form Designer you can easily Change the attributes, like Background Color, ForeColor etc.
After building the form you can easily klick on "File" --> Save to ASE.
And then you have the Form in $PS Code. There you can see how to manipulate the Form.

Greetz Eldo.Ob